# Snowlfake JSON Key value changes, SQL required

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I change the keys to other names? From `country` to `COUNTRY`

```
ID RECORD 2 { "country": "England", "id": "100200", "status": "morestatus" } 3 { "country": "AMERICA", "id": "100300", "status": "morestatus" } 1 { "country": "UK", "id": "100100", "status": "somestatus" } ID RECORD 2 { "COUNTRY": "England", "id": "100200", "status": "morestatus" } 3 { "COUNTRY": "AMERICA", "id": "100300", "status": "morestatus" } 1 { "COUNTRY": "UK", "id": "100100", "status": "somestatus" }
```

I tried this but it seems this works for the values of "country" and can't change the country to COUNTRY

```
UPDATE "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA"."TARGET" T SET T.RECORD =OBJECT_INSERT(T.RECORD:'country','COUNTRY', TRUE) WHERE RECORD:"country" = 'country';
```

[image: JSON Data Key value changes]

Comment: I want to rename the country in all three lines to COUNTRY

Comment: Can you please explain the desired output and what you've tried so far? It's also preferable to share input data as text. Pictures have a tendency to disappear and people looking for answers to similar questions won't be able to benefit from indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest OBJECT_DELETE and OBJECT_INSERT to add a key with the old value and delete the key.

```
create temp table t1 as select parse_json('{ "country": "England", "id": "100200", "status": "morestatus" }') as V;

select * from t1;

select object_delete(object_insert(v, 'COUNTRY', v:country), 'country') from t1;
```

To persist the change, just do an UPDATE:

```
update t1 set v = object_delete(object_insert(v, 'COUNTRY', v:country), 'country');
```

Comment: But how can I make the permanent change from country to COUNTRY in the records

Comment: You can just use UPDATE with the syntax shown. I think I updated the answer on a day Stackoverflow was performing maintenance, so I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to `object_insert` need to be corrected. The update flag will have no effect here since JSON has case-sensitive keys.

Try

```
UPDATE "KAFKA_DB"."KAFKA_SCHEMA"."TARGET" T SET T.RECORD = OBJECT_INSERT(T.RECORD,'COUNTRY', T.RECORD:country);
```

`WHERE RECORD:"country" = 'country';` is also limiting your updates to rows where the `country` key has value `country` which is probably not what you want.